# Include file in function.php based on post type

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to include different file in function.php file of my wordpress theme based on different custom post type using admin_init hook. Is it possible?

I found the solution and added as an answer.

Comment: Rather asking "is it possible?" try to actually do some research and do it on your own. Wordpress isn't rocketsience.

Comment: I did . But can not figure it out.

Comment: What I would do: 1) open your favorite search engine and type "wordpress get post type" 2) This has lead me to a [reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type) 3) With some php logic you would be able to achieve what you want

Comment: I already tried this. I need to include those files using admin_init hook . get_post_type( $post ) give me 'testimonial' for any post type

Comment: Well then, add what you tried in your question. It now seems that you want us to do the work for you

Comment: If you found the solution then post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action('admin_init', 'include_files');

function include_files()
{
    global $pagenow;

    if ('post.php' == $pagenow && isset($_GET['post']) )
    {
        $post_type = get_post_type(esc_attr($_GET['post'])) ;
    }

    else if ('post-new.php' == $pagenow && isset($_GET['post_type']) )
    {
        $post_type = $_GET['post_type'];
    } 

    if($post_type == 'custom_post'){
        include_once('file1.php');
    }else{
        include_once('file2.php');
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what are you trying to achieve here? You can use php functions in your functions.php file and call the functions up in your template files.

I.e. for post-listing or whatever you have the custom posts named, you should be calling the functions from there.

Although, your information is a bit vague and i can't figure out what you are trying to do. However, your approach is bad and i'm 100% sure there's a better way to do it.

Please go to http://codex.wordpress.org/ for detailed reference - anything you need is there, just learn to understand the information presented.

Hope it helps